# Can't import react component into a gatsby starter component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

newbie in Gatsby and React. I am trying to import this responsive navbar [React component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-animate-navbar) into [this Gatsby starter](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/ryanwiemer/gatsby-starter-gcn/):

Instead of the Menu component in the starter, I created a MenuBar, which I call from another component called Layout.

The code on top works (slightly modified from starter), not using external component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { useSiteMetadata } from '../hooks/use-site-metadata'

const Header = styled.header`
  background: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary};
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
`
const Nav = styled.nav`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: ${props => props.theme.sizes.maxWidth};
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5em;

  ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
    h2 {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      @media (max-width: ${props => props.theme.responsive.small}) {
        font-size: 1em;
      }
    }
    &:first-of-type {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      flex-basis: 100%;
      h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        @media (max-width: ${props => props.theme.responsive.small}) {
          font-size: 1em;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    border-bottom: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.text};
    &:hover {
      color: #e8e6e6;
    }
  }
`

const activeLinkStyle = {
  color: 'white',
}

const Menu = () => {
  const { menuLinks } = useSiteMetadata()
  return (
    <Header>
      <Nav>
        <ul>
          {menuLinks.map(link => (
            <li key={link.name}>
              <Link to={link.slug} activeStyle={activeLinkStyle}>
                <h2>{link.name}</h2>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Nav>
    </Header>
  )
}

export default Menu
```

But this one below (where I import the "responsive animate navbar" does not work). I think it has to do with the render metho. Maybe my question is more on Javascript? Any help on getting it to work is welcome. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { useSiteMetadata } from '../hooks/use-site-metadata'
import ReactNavbar from 'react-responsive-animate-navbar'

class MenuBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactNavbar
        color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
        logo="https://svgshare.com/i/KHh.svg"
        menu={[
          { name: 'HOME', to: '/' },
          { name: 'ARTICLES', to: '/articles' },
          { name: 'ABOUT ME', to: '/about' },
          { name: 'CONTACT', to: '/contact' },
        ]}
        social={[
          {
            name: 'Linkedin',
            url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/nazeh-taha/',
            icon: ['fab', 'linkedin-in'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Facebook',
            url: 'https://www.facebook.com/nazeh200/',
            icon: ['fab', 'facebook-f'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Instagram',
            url: 'https://www.instagram.com/nazeh_taha/',
            icon: ['fab', 'instagram'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Twitter',
            url: 'http://nazehtaha.herokuapp.com/',
            icon: ['fab', 'twitter'],
          },
        ]}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default MenuBar
```

**I get this error:**

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
Check the render method of `MenuBar`.
▶ 21 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
/home/neto/Documents/gatsbyto/elindustrial/.cache/app.js:165
  162 |   dismissLoadingIndicator()
  163 | }
  164 | 
> 165 | renderer(<Root />, rootElement, () => {
  166 |   apiRunner(`onInitialClientRender`)
  167 | 
  168 |   // Render query on demand overlay
```

**Edit:**
Thanks Ferran! Actually I was including React from 'react' in both files since at the top from the beginning but they were not appearing in my question because I messed up the formatting :). I read about named Exports vs Default Exports. I tried leaving it as a class, and also changed to a functional component, but I get the exact same error in both cases.

I have also tried importing from Layout using:

```
import MenuBar from '../components/MenuBar'
```

or

```
import {MenuBar} from '../components/MenuBar'
```

But I keep failing miserably with the exact same error above. I installed the component according to the [Gatsby guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/adding-react-components/), I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Edit 2:**
Wrapped ReactNavBar in an empty tag as suggested, Ferran. And I am reading about functional components, still no luck :-S. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactNavbar from 'react-responsive-animate-navbar'

const MenuBar = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <ReactNavbar
        color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
        logo="https://svgshare.com/i/KHh.svg"
        menu={[
          { name: 'HOME', to: '/' },
          { name: 'ARTICLES', to: '/articles' },
          { name: 'ABOUT ME', to: '/about' },
          { name: 'CONTACT', to: '/contact' },
        ]}
        social={[
          {
            name: 'Linkedin',
            url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/nazeh-taha/',
            icon: ['fab', 'linkedin-in'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Facebook',
            url: 'https://www.facebook.com/nazeh200/',
            icon: ['fab', 'facebook-f'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Instagram',
            url: 'https://www.instagram.com/nazeh_taha/',
            icon: ['fab', 'instagram'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Twitter',
            url: 'http://nazehtaha.herokuapp.com/',
            icon: ['fab', 'twitter'],
          },
        ]}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default MenuBar
```

**Edit 3**
Including Layout code.
I ran gastby clean but still got the same error. I notice a warning when I build, this is the warning:

```
warn "export 'default' (imported as 'ReactNavbar') was not found in
'react-responsive-animate-navbar'
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { Global } from '@emotion/core'
// import Menu from '../components/Menu'
import MenuBar from '../components/MenuBar'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/globalStyles.js'

const Root = styled.div``

const Skip = styled.a`
  padding: 0 1rem;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #2867cf;
  color: white;
  z-index: 101;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  &:focus,
  &:active,
  &:hover {
    top: 0;
  }
`

const Layout = props => {
  function handleFirstTab(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
      document.body.classList.add('user-is-tabbing')
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => window.addEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab), [])

  return (
    <Root className="siteRoot">
      <div className="siteContent">
        <Skip href="#main" id="skip-navigation">
          Skip to content
        </Skip>
        <MenuBar />
        <div id="main">{props.children}</div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
      <Global styles={globalStyles} />
    </Root>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined.

In 99% of the cases, this issue is related to the import/export method, if some component is exported as default but imported as named (or vice versa) it will cause the prompted issue.

In your case, you are returning a class-based component but your issue doesn't come from that. You are missing the importation of `React` and `Component` since you are extending it. Following the dependency example:

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { useSiteMetadata } from '../hooks/use-site-metadata'
import { ReactNavbar } from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MenuBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactNavbar
        color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
        logo="https://svgshare.com/i/KHh.svg"
        menu={[
          { name: 'HOME', to: '/' },
          { name: 'ARTICLES', to: '/articles' },
          { name: 'ABOUT ME', to: '/about' },
          { name: 'CONTACT', to: '/contact' },
        ]}
        social={[
          {
            name: 'Linkedin',
            url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/nazeh-taha/',
            icon: ['fab', 'linkedin-in'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Facebook',
            url: 'https://www.facebook.com/nazeh200/',
            icon: ['fab', 'facebook-f'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Instagram',
            url: 'https://www.instagram.com/nazeh_taha/',
            icon: ['fab', 'instagram'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Twitter',
            url: 'http://nazehtaha.herokuapp.com/',
            icon: ['fab', 'twitter'],
          },
        ]}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default MenuBar
```

Using a functional component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactNavbar } from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";


const MenuBar = (props) => {
  return <>
    <ReactNavbar
      color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
      logo="https://svgshare.com/i/KHh.svg"
      menu={[
        { name: `HOME`, to: `/` },
        { name: `ARTICLES`, to: `/articles` },
        { name: `ABOUT ME`, to: `/about` },
        { name: `CONTACT`, to: `/contact` }
      ]}
      social={[
        {
          name: `Linkedin`,
          url: `https://www.linkedin.com/in/nazeh-taha/`,
          icon: [`fab`, `linkedin-in`]
        },
        {
          name: `Facebook`,
          url: `https://www.facebook.com/nazeh200/`,
          icon: [`fab`, `facebook-f`]
        },
        {
          name: `Instagram`,
          url: `https://www.instagram.com/nazeh_taha/`,
          icon: [`fab`, `instagram`]
        },
        {
          name: `Twitter`,
          url: `http://nazehtaha.herokuapp.com/`,
          icon: [`fab`, `twitter`]
        }
      ]}
    />
  </>
};

export default MenuBar;
```

---

### Solution

Diving into the library, it seems that the module is not exported as default (as it can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/Nazeh-Taha/react-responsive-animate-navbar/blob/master/src/index.js#L18)) as the documentation suggests so it needs to be imported as:

```
import { ReactNavbar } from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Ferran! I messed up the formatting, the React import was there from the beginning. Tried both classes and functional component but keep getting the same error. Wonder what am I messing up now.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but it didn't work unfortunately. Will read more about functional components. I have the impression this should work if I use just React without gatsby.

Comment: It's the same. Everything that works in React works in Gatsby, it doesn't make sense to separate both things. Clean the cache by `gatsby clean` during the trials. Check also the page where you are importing the MenuBar, maybe there are something wrong there

Comment: I ran gatsby clean, then gastby develop and keep getting the error. I got this warning too: warn "export 'default' (imported as 'ReactNavbar') was not found in
'react-responsive-animate-navbar'

Comment: I found it. Needs to be imported as: import { ReactNavbar } from "react-responsive-animate-navbar"; Answer updated

Comment: That was it! You are the best, Ferran, thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad to help :) If the issue has been solved please accept the answer to close the issue

Comment: Done. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Here, MenuBar is a class component

Hence, you cannot import hooks in it.

try removing the below line from MenuBar component

```
import { useSiteMetadata } from '../hooks/use-site-metadata'
```

Comment: Thanks Phani. That didn't work, unfortunately. I only left the import of React and ReactNavBar and got the same error.